# Proving $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_n^{n+1}\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, riemann-integration

Prove the following:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_n^{n+1}\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx=0$$

I tried to solve it using the Riemann integral definition with the partition $1/n$:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f(a+\frac{b-a}{n}k)\frac{b-a}{n}$$

But I got stuck.
any suggestions or hints for how to approach it?

Comment: Your integrand approaches 0 as x tends to infinity. See how you can use this to bound the integral from above for sufficiently large N

Comment: That's also not the correct use of Riemann partitions. Nowhere is there a series with infinitely many terms, and "$n$" is not defined there

Comment: $\dfrac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} < \dfrac{1}{\sqrt x}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that

$$0\le \int_n^{n+1}\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx \le \int_n^{n+1}\frac1{\sqrt{x}}dx=2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)=\frac2{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}\to 0 $$

---

As noticed in the comments, more simply

$$0\le \int_n^{n+1}\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx \le \int_n^{n+1}\frac1{\sqrt{x}}dx\le \int_n^{n+1}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}dx=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\to 0$$

---

Another way, since $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \to 0$ as $x\to \infty$ by definition $\forall \varepsilon>0\;\; \exists \delta\;\; \forall x\ge \delta \;\;f(x)\le\varepsilon$ then $\forall n\ge \delta$

$$\int_n^{n+1}f(x)\;dx \le \int_n^{n+1}\varepsilon \;dx =\varepsilon$$

and therefore by definition $f(x)=\int_n^{n+1}\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx\to 0$ which holds in general by the same argument for any $f(x)\to 0$.

Comment: Or $\int_n^{n+1}\frac1{\sqrt{x}}dx < \int_n^{n+1}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}dx = \frac1{\sqrt{n}}$ – as pointed out in a comment, we only need that the integrand converges to zero, an explicit computation of the integral is not needed.

Comment: Very nice this way!

Answer (score 3):

Define $$F(x) := \int_1^x \frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\, dx$$
By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $F$ is differentiable, and
$$F'(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
for all $x > 1$.

Choose any $n\in \Bbb N$, $n\ge 2$. Then $$\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\, dx = F(n+1) - F(n) = \frac{F(n+1)-F(n)}{(n+1)-n}$$
By the Mean Value Theorem applied to $F$, there exists $c_n \in (n,n+1)$ such that
$$ \frac{F(n+1)-F(n)}{(n+1)-n} = F'(c_n) = \frac{\sqrt{c_n-1}}{\sqrt{c_n^2+1}}$$
Using the bounds $n < c_n < n+1$, we have
$$\frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{(n+1)^2+1}} < \frac{\sqrt{c_n-1}}{\sqrt{c_n^2+1}} < \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$$
To summarize,
$$\frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{(n+1)^2+1}} < \int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\, dx < \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$$
Using the Squeeze Theorem with $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{(n+1)^2+1}} = 0 \quad \text{and}\quad \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} = 0$$
it follows immediately that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} = 0$$

Comment: A bit too complicated IMO if you can simply argue that $\frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{(n+1)^2+1}} < \frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} < \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$ for $n \le x \le n+1$ :)

Comment: You're right! I don't know why I did this. @MartinR

Answer (score 1):

By the MVT for integrals, there is $c\in(n,n+1)$ such that
$$\int_n^{n+1}\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx=\frac{\sqrt{c-1}}{\sqrt{c^2+1}}. $$
Note that if $n\to\infty$, $c\infty$ and
$$ \lim_{c\infty}\frac{\sqrt{c-1}}{\sqrt{c^2+1}}=0$$
and hence
$$ \lim_{n\infty}\int_n^{n+1}\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx=0. $$